# Is there a word to describe someone/something that is given a title prematurely?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, vocabulary

For example a coal refered to as a diamond when it hasn't been transformed into one.

Comment: There, edited the question... and yes.

Comment: What is your comment agreeing with?

Comment: Don't count your chickens until they hatch.

Comment: Agreeing to an edit suggestion but user deleted.

Comment: (Not an answer … I found this question whilst half-intending to ask a question about _untimely promotion_.)